# Cannot hide/unhide button inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to unhide a button inside a form. Outside the form it is working.
Also, is there a better way to easily do what I am trying?

```
 <script>
    function action() { 
      document.getElementById('hidden').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
<input type="text" onChange="action();" id="textfield" name="textfield" />
<input type="button" style="visibility: hidden" id="hidden" value="i am here" />
```

Comment: I am not seeing any form in your code

Comment: Your code works great in jsFiddle (note that `onChange` is only triggered after the input field loses focus): https://jsfiddle.net/5d930jee/

Comment: Maybe use onkeyup instead of onChange

Comment: Here's the fiddle with onkeyup function https://jsfiddle.net/mehar/mjuj7r2q/

Comment: No it doesnt work when he add a `<form>` @MaximillianLaumeister.. see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/kmjL0r2c/2/). please see my answer ..

Comment: It was because of the function name "action". But the onkeyup would solve it too. Thanks

 I was able to solve this problem also by using jquey hide/show(). Do you think it is a better practice than by changing style? Or kind of irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/kmjL0r2c/)

That is due to the function name `action()`. May be the `<form>` confuses the function name -action with the form attribute- action. Thus, to make it working, just rename the function to `action1()` for example and it will work.

See the js

```
 function action1() {
   document.getElementById('hidden').style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
```

Comment: So it was that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I try to be careful with id names that I don't accidentally use key words with the id name. Try changing the id="hidden" to id="btnIAmHere". Also action is already a method of a form.

Another way to hide something is to set style.display="none". To make it visible again, set style.display="block"

The difference between these two ways to make something invisible is that setting the visibility doesn't remove the space the object took up.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
I was able to solve this problem also by using jquey hide/show(). Do you think it is a better practice than by changing style? Or kind of irrelevant?

Comment: jquery.hide/show() hides or shows by changing the display property. This hides the element as if it wasn't there and items below it move up. Setting the visibility property to hidden hides the item, but the items below it don't move up. Also, the jquery.show() method sets the style.display to "inline". But there are many more exotic values for the display property. : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 1):

just call the method like this :

```
<input type="text" onChange="window.action();" id="textfield" name="textfield" />
```

I'm not sure but I think it's because the scope is not the same.